# Load elixir configs hierarchal in multiple projects

Tags: config, loading, elixir

I am writing a small project in Elixir, where I will use the built in configuration capability. The way it looks like I have a general project that will call APIs:

api/confix.exs:

```
use Mix.Config

config :api, :status, "awesome"
```

I now have a second project that should utilize these variables

api_consumer/mix.exs

```
def application do
  [applications: [:logger, :api]]
end
```

When I run a console in api_consumer accessing the variable yields a nil result.

```
iex -S mix

iex(1)> Application.get_env(:api, :status)
=> nil
```

From what I understand (and from what I read [here](http://www.schmitty.me/taking-advantage-of-mix-config/)) that should work.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

`mix.exs` is used to configure the *current* application, while `config.exs` is used to configure *other* applications. In your `:api` application, you should put the default values in the `application/0` function inside `mix.exs`:

```
# api/mix.exs

def application do
  [
    applications: [:logger, :api],
    env: [status: "awesome"]
  ]
end
```

Then, you can override this setting in your `:api_consumer` application inside the `config.exs` file:

```
# api_consumer/config/config.exs

config :api, status: "fantastic"
```

More info can be found [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html#application-environment-and-configuration).